# Subclassing numpy ndarray problem

Tags: python, numpy, subclass, recarray

I would like to subclass numpy ndarray. However, I cannot change the array. Why `self = ...` does not change the array? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np

class Data(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, inputarr):
        obj = np.asarray(inputarr).view(cls)
        return obj

    def remove_some(self, t):
        test_cols, test_vals = zip(*t)
        test_cols = self[list(test_cols)]
        test_vals = np.array(test_vals, test_cols.dtype)

        self = self[test_cols != test_vals] # Is this part correct?

        print len(self) # correct result

z = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)],
    dtype=[('a', int), ('b', int), ('c', int)])
d = Data(z)
d.remove_some([('a',4)])

print len(d)  # output the same size as original. Why?
```

Comment: please provide your expected output, it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want remove the rows from the Data instance.

Comment: Ok, you might use a mask, but better if you ask another question as this has not much to do with subclassing ndarray

Comment: [Another question has been posted][1] with the same issue when subclassing a `ndarray`.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049437/add-new-items-to-some-structured-array-in-a-dictionary-like-way/16114640#16114640

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps make this a function, rather than a method:

```
import numpy as np

def remove_row(arr,col,val):
    return arr[arr[col]!=val]

z = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)],
    dtype=[('a', int), ('b', int), ('c', int)])

z=remove_row(z,'a',4)
print(repr(z))

# array([(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)], 
#       dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4')])
```

---

Or, if you want it as a method,

```
import numpy as np

class Data(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, inputarr):
        obj = np.asarray(inputarr).view(cls)
        return obj

    def remove_some(self, col, val):
        return self[self[col] != val]

z = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)],
    dtype=[('a', int), ('b', int), ('c', int)])
d = Data(z)
d = d.remove_some('a', 4)
print(d)
```

The key difference here is that `remove_some` does not try to modify `self`, it merely returns a new instance of `Data`.

Comment: This is perhaps a helpful response to the question, but is not an answer. Why does self = ... not change the value? Maybe the answer is below? I'll repost otherwise.

Comment: Imagine `d`, your `Data` instance. It is pointing to a block of memory which holds the underlying data. To remove a column *in-place*, you'd have to move the other columns together and then resize the array. When you say `self = some_other_array` you are redirecting the variable name `self` to another block of memory. Outside the `remove_row` method, however, the variable name `d` is still pointing to the original block of memory. So it fails to modify `d`.

Comment: All the advice I've ever read about numpy says one should not try to resize numpy arrays. It is possible to do, but all the copying makes it slow. It is better to use slices to create views, or fancy indexing to create new arrays with the desired data. Yes, making a new array also involves copying, but at least you are saved from the complexity of shifting data around in-place.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are not getting the result you expect is because you are re-assigning `self` within the method `remove_some`.  You are just creating a new local variable `self`.  If your array shape were not to change, you could simply do self[:] = ... and you could keep the reference to `self` and all would be well, but you are trying to change the shape of `self`.  Which means we need to re-allocate some new memory and change where we point when we refer to `self`.

I don't know how to do this.  I thought it could be achieved by `__array_finalize__` or `__array__` or `__array_wrap__`.  But everything I've tried is falling short.

Now, there's another way to go about this that doesn't subclass `ndarray`.  You can make a new class that keeps an attribute that is an ndarray and then override all the usual `__add__`, `__mul__`, etc..  Something like this:

```
Class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, inarr):
        self._array = np.array(inarr)
    def remove_some(x):
        self._array = self._array[x]
    def __add__(self, other):
        return np.add(self._array, other)
```

Well, you get the picture.  It's a pain to override all the operators, but in the long run, I think more flexible.

You'll have to read [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) thoroughly to do it right.  There are methods like  `__array_finalize__` that need to be called a the right time to do "cleanup".

Comment: I thought that `__array_finalize__` is used when a new instance is being initiated, for example in adding extra attributes.

Comment: I thought it had to be called any time you re-allocated the array like the OP is doing.  But to be honest, this is over my head.  `__array_wrap__` seems maybe closer to what is wanted, but only returns when called by a ufunc.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the same, but it is really very complex to subclass ndarray.

If you only have to add some functionality, I would suggest to create a class which stores the array as attribute.

```
class Data(object):

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def remove_some(self, t):
        //operate on self.array
        pass

d = Data(z)
print(d.array)
```

Comment: [Documentation on how to sub class ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) might help make it easier.