# Changing subclassed `ndarray` view in-place

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a simple `Test` class which inherits from `numpy.ndarray` ([documentation on `ndarray` subclassing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.subclassing.html)). This class creates an object which is a partial view of another `ndarray`. Now I would like to create a method that modifies this view in-place. Something like:

```
import numpy


class Test(numpy.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, info='Test class'):
        base = numpy.ndarray.__new__(cls, (6, 2), dtype=float)
        view = base[0:2, :]
        view.info = info
        return view

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def change_view(self, start, stop):
        """This is the method I'd like to implement"""
        # Incorrect, but represents what I am looking for
        self = self.base[start:stop]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    print(t)
    print(t.info)
    t.change_view(1, 5)
    print(t)
    print(t.info)
```

I would expect the method `.change_view(x)` to modify the view of the `.base` attribute to show rows `[1:5]` instead of `[0:2]`, which is the default in `__new__()`.

Is this possible? If so, how? Otherwise, why not? Note that `.base` never changes (it always occupies the same memory space), I just want to change the view of it.

### Notes

- See the comments in `change_view()`. I know `self = self.base[start:stop]` is not correct, and I know and understand why, but I think it is a short way to represent what I am looking for.
- As noted in the answers bellow, one could think of `self[:] = ...` or `self.data = ...`. However, this will not work when changing the view size (which is exactly the case).

### References

This question [was already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149269/subclassing-numpy-ndarray-problem) (or at least it is a similar case), but answers referred to solutions which returned the modified array (i.e. no in-place modification) or which used a wrapper object (i.e. having an attribute with the array that is to be modified).

I am aware of those possibilities, and I know they can be simpler or even more convenient. However, I would like to understand why (if so) it is not possible to do what I am looking for.

Comment: If you change `data`, `dimensions` and `strides` field of `PyArrayObject`, then you change the view in place, but DO NOT DO THAT. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) <del>You can't change what data an ndarray instance or subclass instance points to in-place. Sorry!</del> It turns out that it is possible to change which data an ndarray instance points to in-place, but it's a terrible idea and will hopefully be removed soon :-). See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7093

2) Your attempt to assign to `self` like that will only change the binding of the `self` variable inside the method's local binding, and I'm afraid this suggests a fairly fundamental misunderstanding of how Python's execution and object model work. I only bring this up because successfully subclassing `ndarray` is *hard*. *Really* hard. Verging on impossible. (The developers of the popular `pandas` library gave up, for example.) Despite the misleading impression given by that documentation, numpy is not really designed to support subclassing, and it does not work very well. I'd generally recommend that nobody at all attempt to subclass `ndarray`; if you're not already an expert Python programmer than this goes tenfold. Probably we would have deleted that stupid page and disabled subclassing altogether except that it would break backwards compatibility :-(. I'd suggest finding a different strategy to approach your problem.

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, thanks for your answer. I know about `2)`, it was just a short way to show what I wanted to do (even if it is wrong, I think anybody can understand the idea). However, I was expecting an answer that concentrated more in `1)`. If it is not possible, could you please elaborate a bit more? :-)

Comment: "All [impossible things] are alike; each [possible thing] is [possible] in its own way." -- not!Tolstoy. Uh, that is, what elaboration do you want? Not possible = no way to do it = there's not much to elaborate on?

Answer (score 1):

When you write code like

```
var = value
```

it assigns new value to `var` and drops old value, however this is true only in current scope and all other aliases to previous value of `var` stay unchanged. Python's `self` is nothing special, it's just a variable, hence when you write

```
self = self.base[start:stop]
```

you just assign value of `self.base[start:stop]` to the local variable `self` but the value previsouly contained in `self` was not changed as well as all other references that value (which is an instance of your Test class that you want to mutate). You can test it with the following implementation of `change_view`:

```
def change_view(self, start, stop):
    """This is the method I'd like to implement"""
    # Incorrect, but represents what I am looking for
    print('before assignment')
    print(self)
    self = self.base[start:stop]
    print('after assignment')
    print(self)
    print('end change_view')
```

I think running your code with this implementation should clear things up a bit.
Possible implementation might be similar to this:

```
def change_view(self, start, stop):
    """This is the method I'd like to implement"""
    # Incorrect, but represents what I am looking for
    self[:] = self.base[start:stop]
```

The important difference is that it mutates the value contained in the variable `self` instead of assigning new value to the variable. I think something like this should work with python lists, but `numpy.ndarray` is more complex. Moreover since it's implemented in `C` it might be impossible at all. For example you'll need to resize the view somehow, but you can't use `numpy.ndarray.resize` because views don't own it's data; simply assigning `size` and `shape` won't work too.

Comment: Hi zaquest, thanks for your answer. Your conclusion, however, is just the same as mine: it "might" be impossible. But that means it might be possible as well. What I am trying to find is a definite answer (considering this particular problem, in which only the view is to be changed and the `base` array can be considered as static, occupying the same memory space). ;-)